# Localizing app icons in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, localization, ios4

Ok, this one is driving me crazy...

I've had my app icon localized using InfoPlist.strings with language-specific CFBundleIconFile values (selecting different icon for each of the supported languages).

Since iOS 4 this method no longer works, and I'm struggling to find one that does.

Apple docs state that it should be enough to put correct Icon.png files in the appropripate language.lproj folders, but this doesn't seem to work for app icons (everything else gets localized just fine).

I wonder if someone has found any solution that works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the language.lproj folders manually and then in each one of them create a InfoPlist.strings file. Inside the file enter the following: `CFBundleIconFile = "Icon_en.png";` or `CFBundleIconFile = "Icon_es.png";`
It doesn't matter where the actual pngs are.

Comment: This didn't work! I've been trying for an hour to get my app icon localized. I just found a thread on the Apple forums stating that the app icon is not currently localizable.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried with different icons for different languages, but I have tried different display name for same app in different languages. So, I am not sure about this solution but you can give it a try. Here is what I did:

1. Localised my InfoPlist.strings file, in all the languages in which I wanted to translate my app.
2. then I added following code to each of them in their respective languages.
   For English:

   "CFBundleDisplayName" = "england";
   "CFBundleName" = "england";

For French:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "france";
```

"CFBundleName" = "france";

You can try using "icon files" property here.
Well I am still not sure.. I hope this would work.