# Localized App Icon for iOS apps

Tags: ios, localization, icons

I can localize images by put them in .lproj directory, but the application icon cannot be localized by the same approach. Is there any ways to localize the app icon? thanks.

Comment: If you're using iOS 4, this has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328839/localizing-app-icons-in-ios-4

Answer (score 2):

AFIK the only way to achieve this would be to release multiple apps having different icons.

Answer (score -1):

If it was possible to update the App Icon at **runtime** then you could do it if you took the current locale and changed the icon according to that:

- [Updating iOS badge without push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861131/updating-ios-badge-without-push-notifications)
- [Changing Icon per Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038305/changing-icon-per-day)